# Terminal can't see or find dms file

Tags: macos, dms

I am trying to install MuJoCo Garage on my Mac. Following instructions to obtain a computer id for a license, I downloaded getid_osx.dms. 
However, when I ls downloads it doesn't show up.  When I try and chmod it, it can't find the file.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you see it in the Finder? Also, does the browser you used to download it have an option to show & locate recent downloads? If you can find it in Finder, you can drag it into a Terminal window and it'll paste in the full path to the file, which you be able to use with `ls`, `chmod`, etc.

Comment: Yes, I can see it in the Finder. I dragged it into the Terminal and it attached to the full path. Then I tried to check if it was saved and got an error:  LewIss-MacBook-Pro:garage-master lewleib$ /Users/lewleib/AdaptiveStressTestingToolbox/Toolbox/garage-master/getid_osx.dms cd ..
-bash: /Users/lewleib/AdaptiveStressTestingToolbox/Toolbox/garage-master/getid_osx.dms: Permission denied

Comment: Any comment https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davissonn

Comment: At this point, you know where it is -- in /Users/lewleib/AdaptiveStressTestingToolbox/Toolbox/garage-master, not in /Users/lewleib/Downloads. But I'm unfamiliar with MuJoCo Garage, and I don't know what format this is (is it a file or directory?), or why it would need `chmod`ing. What does `ls -ld /Users/lewleib/AdaptiveStressTestingToolbox/Toolbox/garage-master/getid_osx.dms` show?

Comment: It is a executable key for a student license: http://www.mujoco.org/forum/index.php?threads/having-trouble-extracting-getid_osx-dms.3556/.  It is in a disk writing format.  When I ls -ls, I get

Comment: It is an executable key to obtain a license to MuJoCo in a compression format used by Amiga DISKMASHER:  http://www.mujoco.org/forum/index.php?threads/having-trouble-extracting-getid_osx-dms.3556/.  When I do "ls -ld", I get:     -bash: /Users/lewleib/AdaptiveStressTestingToolbox/Toolbox/garage-master/getid_osx.dms: Permission denied

Comment: Is the directory it's in protected? What if you do `ls -ld /Users/lewleib/AdaptiveStressTestingToolbox/Toolbox/garage-master` (and if that gets a permission error, `ls -ld /Users/lewleib/AdaptiveStressTestingToolbox/Toolbox` etc).

Comment: That worked.  Here is what I got:                LewIss-MacBook-Pro:garage-master lewleib$ ls -ld
drwxr-xr-x@ 21 lewleib  staff  672 Mar 14 12:32